# Find sum: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^{n+1}}{6^n + 1} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm a little confused about how to find sums. I know that to find the sum, we need to take $\lim_{n\ \to \infty}  s_n$, where $s_n$ is the partial sum. This is confusing for me b/c I have trouble telling the difference between $s_n$ and $a_n$, where $a_n$ is the series formula in $\sum a_n$.

So anyway, this is my approach:

$$s_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{3^{i+1}}{6^i+1} = \frac{9}{7} + \frac{27}{37} + \frac{81}{217} + ...+ \frac{3^{n+1}}{6^n+1}$$

See, I know ultimately that I have to take the limit of $s_n$, however any convergent series (I know this converges) will have a limit = 0. So i'm assuming that in order to find the sum I need to manipulate the sum formula. Is this the right approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure there's a closed-form solution?  Or were you just asked to show that the series converges?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I was asked to show that it converges. And did so by comparison with $(\frac{1}{2})^n$

Comment: Then why are you trying to find the sum?  Perhaps you're under the false impression that if it's easy to show that a series converges, it must also be easy to find its value

Comment: Then you answered the question.  I don't think there's any more to do with this one.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I guess I assumed that the sum exists. Anyway, I guess my question also includes trying to understand the concept of finding sums as well.

Comment: The sum exists.  It's approximately $2.76355818968079$.  But AFAIK there isn't a closed-form formula for it.

Comment: @Romaion what exactly do you mean by "the sum exists"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, forgive my lack of clarity. I mean there is a sum, approx. 2.76355818968079. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to find it by taking the limit of the partial sums.

Comment: @Romaion what does "finding the sum" mean here?  Do you just want more decimal places to your answer, or are you looking for a **closed form** for your sum?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, if by closed form you mean a formula for the partial sum, then yes this is what I mean.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I just read one of your comments above. It seems I was under the impression that it would be easy/possible to find a closed-form solution. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^{i}}{x^{2i}+1}$ is a [Lambert series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertSeries.html) (equ 8) and may be written as a [theta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) as found by Jacobi (equ 4 [here](https://archive.org/stream/fundamentanovat00jacogoog#page/n118/mode/2up)).

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac{3^n}{6^n+1}=\frac{3^n}{6^n(1+6^{-n})}=\frac{1}{2^n(1+6^{-n})}=\frac{A}{2^n}-\frac{B}{1+6^{-n}}=\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{12^{-n}}{1+6^{-n}}= \\[6mm]
\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{6^n(6^n+1)}=\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{6^n}+\frac{1}{6^n+1}\quad\Rightarrow\quad\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^{n+1}}{6^n+1}=\\[6mm]
3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{6^n}+\frac{1}{6^n+1}\right)=\color{red}{3\left(1-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{\log6}\left[\varPsi_{1/6}\left(1-\frac{i\,\pi}{\log6}\right)-\log\frac65\right]\right)} \\[8mm]
\small\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\varPsi_{q}(z)\quad\text{q-Polygamma Function}
$$

Answer (score 2):

We have:
$$ S = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{3^{n+1}}{6^n+1}=\sum_{m\geq 1}(-1)^{m+1} \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{3^{n+1}}{6^{nm}}=9\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{6^m-3} \tag{1}$$
and the last series is simple to accelerate:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} S &=& 3-9\sum_{m\geq 2}\frac{(-1)^m}{6^m-3} = 3-9\sum_{m\geq 2}\frac{(-1)^m}{6^m}-27\sum_{m\geq 2}\frac{(-1)^m}{6^m(6^m-3)}\\&=&\color{blue}{\frac{851}{308}}-27\sum_{m\geq 3}\frac{(-1)^m}{6^m(6^m-3)}\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$ 
Since the last series is a fast-converging series with alternating signs, $\left|S-\frac{851}{308}\right|\leq 5\cdot 10^{-4}$, and we may improve such approximation by just following the same approach. However, I do not think the original series has a nice "closed form".

Answer (score 1):

We have the identity
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{n^k\left(6^k+1\right)}
&=\frac1{6n-1}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{(6n)^k}-\frac1{n^k\left(6^k+1\right)}\right)\\
&=\frac1{6n-1}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(6n)^k\left(6^k+1\right)}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
and we can bound the error in $(1)$ after $m$ terms by
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty\frac1{(6n)^k\left(6^k+1\right)}
&\le\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty\frac1{(36n)^k}\\
&=\frac1{(36n-1)(36n)^m}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

---

Using $(1)$, we can reduce the sum to converge as fast as we wish. For example,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{3^{k+1}}{6^k+1}=3\left(1-\frac1{11}+\frac1{71}-\frac1{431}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{432^k\left(6^k+1\right)}\right)\tag{3}
$$
and the error in $(3)$ after $m$ terms is less than
$$
\frac3{2591\cdot2592^m}\tag{4}
$$